# Q object parameters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-q

```
from django.db.models import Q

MODULES_USERS_PERMS = {
    MODULE_METHOD: [],
    MODULE_NEWS: [],
    MODULE_PROJECT: ['created_by', 'leader'],
    MODULE_TASK: [],
    MODULE_TICKET: [],
    MODULE_TODO: []
}
filter_fields = MODULES_USERS_PERMS[MODULE_PROJECT]
perm_q = map(lambda x: Q(x=user), filter_fields)
if perm_q:  #sum(perm_q)
    if len(perm_q) == 1:
        return perm_q[0]
    elif len(perm_q) == 2:
        return perm_q[0] | perm_q[1]
    elif len(perm_q) == 3:
        return perm_q[0] | perm_q[1] | perm_q[2]
```

I do not know how to describe in words what is required by code, I hope he speaks for itself.
I need to make a filter from the list of objects.

Needless code is not working.

UPDATE:
code, that looks better, but not working too:

```
filters = ['created_by', 'leader']
filter_params = Q()
for filter_obj in filters:
    filter_params = filter_params | Q(filter_obj=user)
```

> FieldError at /projects/
>
> Cannot resolve keyword 'filter_obj' into field. Choices are:
>   begin_time, comment, created_at, created_by, created_by_id, end_time,
>   id, leader, leader_id, name, project_task, status, ticket_project

Comment: did you find answer to these problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to combine an unknown number of `Q` objects:

```
import operator
perm_q = reduce(operator.or_, perm_q)
```

Or:

```
summed_q = perm_q[0]
for new_term in perm_q[1:]:
    summed_q = summed_q | new_term
```

Which does the same thing, just more explicitly.

Based on your edit - you need to turn the string contained in your `filter_obj` variable into a keyword argument. You can do this by creating a dictionary to use as the keyword arguments for the `Q` constructor:

```
filters = ['created_by', 'leader']
filter_params = Q()
for filter_obj in filters:
    kwargs = {filter_obj: user}
    filter_params = filter_params | Q(**kwargs)
```